Why does Kour.io keep saying "disable adblocker!" or "ad too short"?
I don't have an adblocker nor any type of ad-disabler. Yet all the ad-based rewards are not claimable for me because it says that I have an adblocker or the ad is too short. How can I fix this problem?

I dont know if its only me but every time i tried to get bonuses with watching an ad on games it almost never worked.

Same... Hopefully somebody finds a solution

Been a while since I played those kind of games... really my best answer would be 'simply dont expect it to work, and dont lose your time on it'. Anyways usually the reward is garbage.

True. Tbh, I'm not a Kour.io player. I'm helping my uncle's son who lives in a relatively remote place.
